# Web scraping using Beautifulsoup to collect dropdown values

Tags: python

I am new to Python, trying to get a list of all the drop down values from the following website "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category" but failing to do so.

The below code is producing an empty list

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from urllib.parse import urljoin
  import re
  import pandas as pd

  page = "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category"
  information = requests.get(page)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(information.content, 'html.parser')
  categories = soup.find_all('select', attrs={'class' :'w3-select w3-border'})
```

The desired output is the below list :-

```
['Alcoholic Beverage','Beer','Bottled 
  Beverage',..........,'Trader','Wholesaler']
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are loaded through Javascript, but the data is on the page. With some crude regexes you can extract it:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/'
text = requests.get(url).text

d = re.findall(r'var\s*cObject\s*=\s*(.*)\s*;', text)[0]
d = re.sub(r'(\w+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', d)
d = json.loads(d.replace("'", '"'))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(d, width=200)
```

Prints:

```
{'category': [{'cat_type': '1', 'id': '1', 'name': 'Alcoholic Beverage', 'permalink': 'alcoholic-beverage', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '2', 'name': 'Beer', 'permalink': 'beer', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '3', 'name': 'Bottled Beverage', 'permalink': 'bottled-beverage', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '4', 'name': 'Canned Beverage', 'permalink': 'canned-beverage', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '5', 'name': 'Carbonated Beverage', 'permalink': 'carbonated-beverage', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '6', 'name': 'Cereal / Grain Beverage', 'permalink': 'cereal-grain-beverage', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '7', 'name': 'Cider', 'permalink': 'cider', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '8', 'name': 'Coffee', 'permalink': 'coffee', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '9', 'name': 'Distilled Water', 'permalink': 'distilled-water', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '10', 'name': 'Fruit / Vegetable Juice', 'permalink': 'fruit-vegetable-juice', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '11', 'name': 'Herbal Beverage', 'permalink': 'herbal-beverage', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '12', 'name': 'Instant Beverage', 'permalink': 'instant-beverage', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '13', 'name': 'Milk', 'permalink': 'milk', 'status': '2'},
              {'cat_type': '1', 'id': '14', 'name': 'Mineral Water', 'permalink': 'mineral-water', 'status': '2'},

...and so on.
```

EDIT: To print just names of categories, you can do this:

```
for c in d['category']:
    print(c['name'])
```

Prints:

```
Alcoholic Beverage
Beer
Bottled Beverage
Canned Beverage
Carbonated Beverage
Cereal / Grain Beverage
Cider

...

Manufacturer
Restaurant
Retail Outlet
Supplier
Trader
Wholesaler
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a proper question but still.

```
categories = soup.find("select", attrs={"name": "ctype"}).find_all('option')

result = [cat.get_text() for cat in categories]
```

Comment: Apologies for not framing my question nicely, and thanks for replying
the code you suggested is throwing the following error :-

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: Edited. Does the page load properly?